# Write a Cursor or procedure to iterate rows of one table with rows of other table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two tables(T1 & T2) having same columns in both.
Table T1 have huge data (~100,000 records), table T2 have 10% of T1.
There are so many rows in table T1 matched with rows of table T2 regarding all columns.But some rows are matched only with specific columns and they are different for rest of columns.

I want to find out for which columns it is different in table T1.

Suppose T1 have `ProdId, Name, Address, Phone` And T2 also have the same columns.
Lets say 50 records matched exactly for every columns.
But 50 records matched with only `ProdId` column, 15 records matched with `ProdId` and `Name` columns. like that.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. please read [ask].

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. If I take the first record of T1 and look at all records in T2, there may be 20 with the same prodid, 100 with the same name, 0 with the same address, 2 with the same phone. And 15 with the same prodid *and* same name, 0 with the same prodid *and* the same address, ... 0 for the same prodid *and* name *and* address *and* phone. This is a lot of information for one record. There are 100000 of them. So this cannot actually be your desired result. So, what *is* your desired result? Show sample data, sample results and describe the desired logic.

Comment: well, you can take flag_columns for unmatched column and set it 'Y' if `ProdId` column is matched, similarly for other columns.

Comment: Take one record from T2 iterate it to every records of T1, you have found 100 records in table T1 matched on the basis of `ProdId`.Now there might have some records which are differ in `address` but have same `ProdId`, also same `ProdId` and `address` but differ in `phone`. I want to know how many are differ according to `address` in table T1,  how many are differ according to `phone` in table T1.(Out of those matched 100 records).

Answer (score 0):

to find differences between 2 table you could do something like

```
select ProdId, Name, Address, Phone
from t1
minus
select ProdId, Name, Address, Phone
from t2
to find the columns .. you could try
something like
select t1.ProdId, t1.Name, t1.Address, t1Phone
from t1 t1
left join t2 t2 on t1.prodid = t2.prodid and t1.name = t2.name --can add columns here...
where t2 id null
```

Comment: I have tried with all those.But i'm not getting expected result.Since Table T1 might have same records multiple times only differ in one or two columns.Like same record but having different `address` and `phone`,

Comment: you can concat the columns and then make the join, something like